# save object in a variable parsing it

Tags: jquery

I have this object:

```
  var eventsDates = new Array(
    "basket":"11-10-2012",
    "soccer":"21-10-2012",
    "soccer":"28-10-2012",
    "baseball":"25-11-2012",
    "baseball":"15-12-2012"
  );
```

and I need to extract dates by competition for example only soccer than save result like this

```
  var eventsDates = new Array(
    "21-10-2012",
    "28-10-2012"
  );
```

any suggestion

Luca

Comment: That's not an object, that's an array with wrong syntax.

Comment: The first object is not correct syntax, and even with the `{}` object notation, you have duplicate keys.

Comment: how should be the syntax

Comment: first determine whether you want to use an object, or an array of objects.  then show what you have tried.  It shouldn't be more than a simple loop.  Then come back if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `arrays` and `objects` use one or the other:

```
var eventDates = [
   "11-10-2012",
   "21-10-2012",
   "28-10-2012",
   "25-11-2012",
   "15-12-2012"
];
```

OR

```
var eventDates = {
  "basket":"11-10-2012",
  "soccer":"21-10-2012",
  "soccer":"28-10-2012",
  "baseball":"25-11-2012",
  "baseball":"15-12-2012"
};
```

That said you cant reuse the same key (like `baseball`) so the best structure would be one of the following:

```
var eventDates = {
  "basket": ["11-10-2012"],
  "soccer": ["21-10-2012", "28-10-2012"]
  "baseball": ["25-11-2012", "15-12-2012"]
};
```

And access like `eventDates.baseball`

```
$.each(eventDates.baseball, function (k, v) {
  alert(v);
});
```

You could also do the following but then you would have to use a custom extractor which would involve iterating over the entire array anytime you want dates only for a certain `name`.

```
var eventDates = [
  {"name": "basket", "date":"11-10-2012"},
  {"name":"soccer", "date":"21-10-2012"},
  {"name": "soccer", "date":"28-10-2012",
  {"name": "baseball", "date":"25-11-2012"},
  {"name":"baseball", "date":"15-12-2012"}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were suggesting you had a series of objects within an array:

```
var events = [
    {"basket":"11-10-2012"},
    {"soccer":"21-10-2012"},
    {"soccer":"28-10-2012"},
    {"baseball":"25-11-2012"},
    {"baseball":"15-12-2012"}
];

var count = events.length, dates = [], m;

while (count--)
    if (m = events[count]["soccer"])
        dates.push(m);

console.log(dates);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YX4Kq/

Comment: Great!
Is it another way to make array putting more dates in the same blockquote?

Comment: @roybatty I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a different data structure for this kind of task:

```
var eventDates = {
    Soccer: [{
         date: ...
    ]},
    Basket: [{
         date: ...
    ]}
};
```

Then you can easily access f.e. all soccer dates:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= eventDates.Soccer.length; i++) {
    // Do something with eventDates.Soccer[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var eventsDates = {
    "basket":["11-10-2012"],
    "soccer":["21-10-2012","28-10-2012"],
    "baseball":["25-11-2012","15-12-2012"]
  }


var soccerDates = eventsDates.soccer;
```